# How to update AWS Secrets Manager via python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I can't find any documentation on how to upload/update values to the AWS secrets manager. I can only retrieve the values via python. Is there a workaround on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`update_secret()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.update_secret):

```py
response = client.update_secret(
    SecretId='string',
    ClientRequestToken='string',
    Description='string',
    KmsKeyId='string',
    SecretBinary=b'bytes',
    SecretString='string'
)
```

For creating *new* secrets, use: [`put_secret_value()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.put_secret_value)

Answer (score 6):

```
import json
from boto3 import Session

# initialize session client

session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id="aws_access_key_id",
    aws_secret_access_key="aws_secret_access_key",
    region_name="region_name"
)

client = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager")

FOR CREATE

client.create_secret(Name="my_first_secret", SecretString=json.dumps({"favorite_character": "stitch!"}))


FOR UPDATE

# get original secrets
original_secret = client.get_secret_value(SecretId="my_first_secret")


# update secrets
updated_secret = original_secret.update({"UPDATE_KEY": "update_value"})
client.update_secret(SecretId="my_secret_name", SecretString=json.dumps(updated_secret))
```

Comment: oh i would not advise to have aws credentials in code. Demo's fine

Comment: We don't really put that in code. If running on EC2, it's already handled by the boto.utils.get_instance_identity() since we're using EC2 roles and avoided using ~/.aws as credentials

Answer (score 2):

```
def init_aws_session():
    region_name = "us-east-1"
    my_access_id = 'my_access_id'
    my_secret_key = 'my_secret_key'
    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session(
        region_name=region_name,
        aws_access_key_id=my_access_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=my_secret_key
    )
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name,
    )
    return client


def update_secret(secret_name, key, value):
    client = init_aws_session()
    # get original secrets
    config_secret = get_secret(secret_name, client)
    secret.update({key: value})
    client.update_secret(SecretId=secret_name, SecretString=json.dumps(secret))
    print(secret)


def get_secret(secret_name):
    client = init_aws_session()

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])

    # Your code goes here.
    return json.loads(secret)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_secret(some_secret, key, value)
```