# AWS secret update using python

Tags: aws-secrets-manager

I used the code snippet from the post [How to update AWS Secrets Manager via python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760957/how-to-update-aws-secrets-manager-via-python/58763334#58763334)

But I am running into an issue with the update secret. After execution of the code in the AWS console, I get the below error when I try to retrieve the secret

> **The secret value can't be converted to key name and value pairs**

Code snippet:

```
updated_secret = original_secret.update({"password":"123admin"}) client.update_secret(SecretId="mysecret", SecretString=json.dumps(updated_secret))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve the value from the response syntax.

```
myrequest={ "ARN": "string", "Name": "string", "VersionId": "string"}

client.update_secret(myrequest)
```

(maybe I forgot the json dump).

You need two requests: to have first update the value with .update, and then get it with .get

See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-secretsmanager-secretsmanager_basics.py.html) and the one about [update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_UpdateSecret.html)

The proper way to do it is:

```
{
   "SecretId": "mysecret",
   "SecretString": "admin123"
}
```

Comment: aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id mysecret --region us-east-1 --secret-string '{"username":"anika","password":"mypwd"}' works fine



But if I pass a variable $serverPwd it does not replace the variable
serverPwd=mypwd



aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id mysecret --region us-east-1 --secret-string '{"username":"anika","password":"$serverPwd"}



Any thoughts how to pass variable